# How to add hashtag and mention in textInput react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm facing this challenge when client want me to add mention and hashtag to the textInput, will look like this

[image]

I tried some lib , but they are not give me the result like this, so i tried to make a custom one,, but i wonder how can we detect when we type "@" or "#", i struggle for days because of this, please help

Comment: Share some code, please?

Comment: Sadly, i just plan how to do this, just try `react-native-controlled-mention` but it not like this, so i want to ask a lib or how to trigger when @ was input or #

Comment: What code do you have for the UI? Regex is your friend.

Comment: I have the TextInput already, but honestly still don't find out how to make this work

Comment: @CODEforDREAM Have you got an answer? If so, please share it with us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is perfect for this:

```js
inputStr.replace(/(?<=#).*?(?=( |$))/g, hashtag => {
    // do something with hashtag, e.g. "fenty"
    return hashtag;
});
```

**Breaking the regex down:**

```
(?<=#)       # match anything preceded by "#"
.*?          # match everything without greedy matching
(
  ?=         # match anything with the following after it:
  ( |$)      # space or end of text
)
```

`g` (global) means to match all occurrences.

The same thing can be done for `@`:

```js
inputStr.replace(/(?<=@).*?(?=( |$))/g, mention => {
    // mention == "fenty"
    return mention;
});
```

You can also perform manipulations on, say, the hashtags to turn them into links or whatever:

```js
const newString = inputStr.replace(/(?<=#).*?(?= )/g, hashtag => {
    // do something with hashtag, e.g. "fenty"
    return `<a href="/hashtags/${hashtag}">${hashtag}</a>`; // "stunna new year highlighter  <a href="/hashtags/fenty">fenty</a> @fenty"
});
```

Demo:

```js
"hello #yes no #maybe so #ionter6 #000".replace(/(?<=#).*?(?=( |$))/g, hashtag => {
    console.log("Hashtag from post:", hashtag);
    return hashtag;
});
```

Comment: Saving my life from client, thank bro

Answer (score 1):

I think you should give this library a try, I did the same using
react-native-controlled-mentions

Comment: Thank for your answer, but how can we move mention below, i see we can make it by use `position:"absolute"` but when text long, it cover the text

Comment: isBottomMentionSuggestionsRender is prop set it to true, you will get it at bottom.